# Accessing specific values of a loop-created dictionary in a Python function

Tags: python, function, loops, dictionary

I am very new to Python and as an exercise I tried solving a basic finance exercise using code. My objective is to get a dictionary of spot rates and then a dictionary of discount rates calculated from those. I had thought to something like this:

```
discountrates={}

def discountrates(n):
    spotrates={}
    for x in range(1,n+1):
        spotrates['s'+str(x)]=float(input('What is s'+str(x)+'? (not in percentage)'))
    for y in range(1,n+1):
         discountrates['d(0,'+str(y)+')']= 1/((1+float(spotrates['s'+str(y)]))**y)
    for key, value in discountrates.items():
        print (key, value)
```

Now the problem is that dictionary items cannot be accessed in a function. When I looked in your forum, I found solutions for unpacking the dictionary but that does not work in my case because I need to access a specific element of the dictionary, whose name cannot be fully specified (as I have seen in the Python manual) because it's part of a loop, in order for the formula to work without having to manually insert anything else. I used a dictionary in the first place to create names that were automatically generated but now I can't seem to get the information out of it.

What is the best solution?

Thanks in advance for the help. It's been driving me crazy.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you called your global variable `discountratesdict` not `discountrates` (which is the name of your function).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you don"t name your dictionary like your function since the later will overwrite the former. In line 1 you say `discountrates` is an empty `dict`, in line 2 you say `discountrates` is a function object. You need to give them different names in python if they are on the same scope.

Furthermore why do you need `discountrates` to be `global`? would you like to keep old rates if `n` is smaller than a previous `n`? For performance I suggest you combine the two loops. Besides that there is no reason why the second loop can't read `for x ...` as well since zou don't use x anymore anyway. As a further hint, if you come to the conclusion, that a global is the only way it might help to add `global discountratesdict`, so it is easier to spot that a global is intended here, even though this is not necessary in your particular case since the `[]`-operator needs an object and thus it already refers to your global.

Putting all this together yields:

```
discountratedict={}

def discountrates(n):
    global discountratedict
    spotrates={}

    for x in range(1,n+1):
        spotrates['s'+str(x)]=float(input('What is s'+str(x)+'? (not in percentage)'))
        discountratedict['d(0,'+str(x)+')']= 1/((1+float(spotrates['s'+str(x)]))**x)

    for key, value in discountratedict.items():
        print (key, value)
```